# Propagate drop events from TinyMCE editor to the parent element

Tags: drag-and-drop, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor embedded in a page in which the outer element has an ondrop handler that uploads dropped files.

However, if the user drops a file on the TinyMCE editor, the parent handler is never called. Regardless of whether I enable or disable drag-drop in the editor, the event never propagates to the parent element.

Is there a way to propagate an ondrop event from the TinyMCE editor to the surrounding element?

Answer (score 0):

The editor itself is an iFrame so if you want to propagate the event you need to make sure you are passing it to the `parent` if you want the page to get the event.

Perhaps you can make a TinyMCE Fiddle or CodePen of what you are doing so people can see what you have tried?

Comment: All I've tried so far is to enable/disable drag-drop in the TinyMCE settings. There doesn't seem to be any way to control how events propagate from the editor iFrame, unless I'm missing something?